# Can somebody help me with posting a status on twitter?

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm pretty much following this tutorial
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/

and i have everything working i can see the screen name when i call it as well as my status time line but for some reason i can not post a status. i have looked everywhere on the internet and everybody does it the same way but i cant get mine to work.

here is my twitter_oauth.php

```
<?php
require("twitteroauth.php");
session_start();

if(!empty($_GET['oauth_verifier']) && !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token']) && !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'])){
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('consumerkey', 'otherkey', $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
    //request the access token
    $access_token = $twitteroauth->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
    $user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
    //useful for seeing array key names
    //print_r($user_info);

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'usernamr', 'password');
    mysql_select_db(' database_twitter');

    if(isset($user_info->error)){
        header('Location: twitter_login.php');
    }else{
        //find the user by its ID
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'twitter' AND oauth_uid = ". $user_info->id);
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        //if it doesnt exist add
        if(empty($result)){
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, oauth_token, oauth_secret) VALUES ('twitter', {$user_info->id}, '{$user_info->screen_name}', '{$access_token['oauth_token']}', '{$access_token['oauth_token_secret']}')");
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " .mysql_insert_id());
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        }else{
            // Update the tokens
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET oauth_token = '{$access_token['oauth_token']}', oauth_secret = '{$access_token['oauth_token_secret']}' WHERE oauth_provider = 'twitter' AND oauth_uid = {$user_info->id}");
        }

            $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $result['username'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_uid'] = $result['oauth_uid'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $result['oauth_provider'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $result['oauth_token'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_secret'] = $result['oauth_secret'];                        



            header('Location: twitter_update.php');
    }
}else{
    header('Location:twitter_login.php');
}
?>
```

and heres twitter_update.php

```
<?php
require("twitteroauth.php");
session_start();
?>
<h2>Hello <?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo '@' .$_SESSION['username'];
}else{
    echo 'Guest';
}

 if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){  
     $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('key', 'key', $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_secret']);  
     $status_timeline = $twitteroauth->get('statuses/home_timeline', array('count' => 40));
    $content = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');

    $twitteroauth->get('users/show', array('screen_name' => 'abraham'));
    //$twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Testing out the twitter api with oauth'));
     //print_r($status_timeline);
     $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "hello world"));


 }
?>
</h2>
```

was trying to find out if it has been updated but couldn't find anything and i'm guessing it isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving the access_token to `$_SESSION['access_token']` in `twitter_oauth.php` but then in `twitter_update.php` you are using `$_SESSION['oauth_token']`.

`twitter_oauth.php` should also build a new `TwitterOAuth` object with the access_token before making requests to the API as the user.

You also have no error handling in the event that getting an access token fails.

Comment: thanks a lot ill check it out in a few i just tried so many different things i must've missed the most obvious. are you the author of oauth?

Comment: I'm the author of this particular PHP library but I am not an author of the OAuth specification.

Comment: I checked what you said and I changed the session name so it does work because I can grab anything I just can't post what do you need to post a status? I even checked my twitter account connections and it shows my application sending whatever I put in the post status but it doesn't tweet it?

Comment: If you set `$result = $twitteroauth->post(...);` and `var_dump($result)` what is Twitter returning?