# Twitter REST API, update status?

Tags: php, javascript, oauth, twitter

I am wanting to allow a user to update their twitter status from my website. I was planning on using Twitter's @anywhere feature, but this was not a very friendly solution:

- Take over 3 seconds to load
- Makes 14 requests
- Calls jQuery twice

Then I found the Twitter REST API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

Using OAuth, I want the user to be able to login, and then update their status using that API. I've been trying to find tutorials on this, but I haven't found any that use the REST API to update the Twitter Status.

Does anyone have code for/know of a tutorial for what I'm looking for?

Comment: I Googled **twitter rest api update status** and got [this code](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update) straight from the API documentation.

Comment: I've seen the documentation, like the link you posted, but I don't know where to begin in terms of letting the user login, authorize app, etc. which is why a tutorial would be helpful (and allow me to learn more in the process)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can somebody help me with posting a status on twitter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425101/can-somebody-help-me-with-posting-a-status-on-twitter)

Comment: Non-programmatic (**dead simple**) alternative: in JavaScript, `window.open('https://twitter.com/share?text=<foo>&url=<bar>')`.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: I would definitely prefer this to using a middleman.

Comment: Me too. So much simpler, impossible to f*ck up.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL Why would you want to use that? It is basically the same thing as linking to twitter and saying "Update your status here"

Comment: For the aforementioned reasons: it's incredibly simple. One line of JavaScript, no libraries needed. The UI is provided for you. **It just works.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adam Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514185/adam-green) has a [nice tutorial in PHP](http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-tutorials/hello-twitter-oauth-php/) that walks you through everything from setting up your application on the Twitter developer site to posting your first tweet.

Comment: That just posts a static tweet though when the page loads, which wouldn't work as I want my site users to update their own status.

Answer (score 2):

Just post the data to update api endpoint.

You can read twitter update api doc for details : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update

And there is a open source twitter client written in PHP, named dabr. http://code.google.com/p/dabr/

Comment: I'll take a look at dabr, have you used it? Do you know if it's easy to strip it down to JUST update a status?

Comment: You should also look at abraham's twitteroauth library - https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Comment: @Charlie Yes, Pls check the dabr source code: common/twitter.php function twitter_update().